# Algorithm for optimal load balancing recommendation over time

Tags: algorithm, optimization, load-balancing, mathematical-optimization, heuristics

I have a problem which I am sure can be solved by one of the classic algorithms but I am not able to figure it out and map  it back.
This may be little long to explain the problem.

So I have few worker machines which has some fixed processes running. Each process has some load. This may happen that one worker is free at some point of day where as others are chocked. I have to generate offline recommendations to point this out and give optimal distribution.

I will explain it more clearly with following example :

There are two workers : **w1 and w2**

worker w1 has two processes **OP1 and OP2**

worker w2 has three process **DB, BC, WG**

I have the data of load by each process for a month, collected every 20 minutes. Now since I have to analyze the data over time, I break the data into four big time window -- *morning, day,eve,night*. Now I take mean load of each process in each time window in each worker. w1 has total resource 10 units and w2 has 15.

[image: worker w1 has total resource 10 units]

[image: worker w2 has total resource 15 units]

*Now from this data I can say that move some DB process work to w1 in night because we find w1 free at night. Similarly other recommendations.*

If I can have an optimal distribution I can always compare and generate recommendations. How do I move ahead? I saw many load balancing problems but they are  real time server request handling problems and  job shop problems have job completion timings as a parameter.

Comment: Do you have a job queue or something similar?

Comment: I dont't understand the problem description. For each worker (*w1* and *w2*) there are four time slots *morning*, *day*, *eve*, and *night*; furthermore there are jobs already assigned to the workers, where each job causes a certain load in each slot. I don't understand what exactly the worker's total resource is.

Comment: @Codor To simplify I have narrowed down the resource to a single value "load". You can think of it as only RAM of the worker. Lets say I just want to balance the RAM utilization.

Comment: @FDL I dont have a job queue. This is offline recommendation. So everything run for a month, and at the end of the month I collect the data and  I want to tell them that -- use my recommendation for next month, you'll save your resources.